mailx not sending to Outlook distribution list?
So I have a Solaris 11 server with mailx.  I am trying to send emails to distribution lists in the company's Outlook (which is not running on this server, it runs on Microsoft's cloud).  I am able to send emails to individuals without trouble.  Then I am able to send emails to SOME distribution lists, but not others.  A coworker of mine who has been here a long time told me there was "some setting in Outlook" that allows mailx to send to distribution lists.  Other people have told me I need to set up an alias file (I've checked the alias file on the server, it is empty, so that does not explain why some distribution lists are working but not others).
By "not working" I mean just that- the emails don't send.  They appear in /var/log/syslog without errors.  But the emails are never received.
I'm at a loss as to what to do.  Any help at all is appreciated.

You said that "the emails don't send. They appear in /var/log/syslog without errors. But the emails are never received". First of all, check the local mail queue to determine whether or not the messages have even left your local system:
mailq

If they have been sent to Microsoft 365 you should see the transmission line in the syslog, and adding these to your question would be useful.
For now, let's assume the messages have left your box.
In the Microsoft 365 world (Exchange Online) there are a couple of settings that manage accessibility:

Can external senders can email the group or not?
Is the group restricted to members or can anyone email it?

Your Exchange Online administrator should be able to check these settings for you:


The other place I would ask your administrator to check is in the Message Flow / Message Trace. This allows someone to check the state of any message received or sent through Exchange Online. So you can provide any of a date/time (range), sender/recipient, or even message id and the processing of any matching message(s) can be investigated.
